# Find the multiplicative inverse of $5$ in $\mathbb Z_{73}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, inverse

I'm having some trouble with this question. The inverse should result in $44$ but I am getting $29$

$$73 = 14 \times 5 + 3$$

$$5 = 1 \times 3 + 2$$

$$3 = 1 \times 2 + 1$$

so $\gcd(73,5)=1$

using back substitution I then get:

$$1 = 3 - (2 \times 1)$$

$$1 = 3-(5 - (3 \times 1))  = 2(3)-5$$

$$1 = 2(73 - (14 \times 5)) - 5$$

$$1 = 2(73) - 29(5)$$

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Actually, if $2\cdot 73-29\cdot 5=1$, then you are done. Just consider it modulo $73$.

Comment: You can eyeball it to get the answer $5\cdot 44 - 73\cdot 3=1$, if you need a positive value. Basically, you need to find a multiple of $73$ that is one less than a multiple of $5$.

Answer (score 4):

Observe $\,-29\equiv 44\mod73$.

Comment: No reason not to just say $-29$ is the solution, of course.

Comment: yeah how did i miss that lol. Thanks